# I need to loop through rows and check checkbox in a datagrid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, ria

Hi I am trying to loop through rows in a datagrid
If I use:

```
PagedCollectionView pgView = dataGrid.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView;
foreach (var item in pgView.)
{}
```

I get the item as entity and I can't figure out how to cast that to some meaningfull data
can anyone help me there ?

if I use:

```
IEnumerable list = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
foreach (var row in list)
{}
```

I get the same entity and the same problem...

I have looked at the following that accomplishes the task but I feel like I am 
mixing data with presentation

```
PagedCollectionView pgView = verkefniDataGrid.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView;
foreach (var item in pgView)
{
((CheckBox)verkefniDataGrid.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(item)).IsChecked = true;
}
```

Are the any way to get to the data behind the item and set it there to true ?

Comment: What are you binding the DataGrid to? I would suggest that you had a view model bound to the view with some data items where these items had a property called "Checked" or "Selected". Then you would bind the checkbox against that property and you would not have to resort to code-behind.

Comment: Thank you for your replay: It is filled with a loadoperation from domaincontext. But the thing is that I may want to select all the rows and set the checkbox to true with one button click. Can I do that with out code behind ?

Comment: Yes, if you have all the items in your view model. The it is a matter of  creating a command to which you bind your button. Then, in the view model, iterate all the items in the PagedCollectionView and set their "Selected" property (Or whatever it is called) to true. With INotifyPropertyChanged it will just work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ViewModel approach, you could define the view like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="151" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,67,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

    </sdk:DataGrid>
    <Button Content="What is selected?" Width="300" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then, you setup the view to be bound against a ViewModel, which contains a property of your PagedCollectionView:

```
public class ViewModel
{        
    private PagedCollectionView _items = new PagedCollectionView(
                new[] 
                {new MyItem{Name="Item 1"},
                new MyItem{Name="Item 2"},
                new MyItem{Name="Item 3"},
                new MyItem{Name="Item 4"}   });

    public PagedCollectionView Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public string GetSelectedItems()
    {
        return "Selected items: " + 
                 string.Join(",", 
                    Items.Cast<MyItem>().Where(x => x.IsSelected).
                      Select(x => x.Name));
    }
}
```

Now, since I don't know your solution that well, I put a piece of ugly code in the code-behind just to show how that the selections are tracked:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var viewModel = DataContext as ViewModel;
     MessageBox.Show(viewModel.GetSelectedItems());
}
```

Connecting the View and ViewModel together is done by creating the view, the view model and then stitch them together with the DataContext property of the view.
Like this:

```
var view = new MyWindow();
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
```

That should make the example work.

Comment: Thank you Per, I think I need to go and read chapter 12 in Pro
Business Applications with Silverlight 4 because I have not yet studied MVVM :)

Comment: Hi Per. I was trying to hook up your example. The Items property that the datagrid is bound to is that aquered like this:     <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="Items" />
</UserControl.Resources>

Comment: Hi Ami. When you create your View, the usercontrol, you assign its DataContext to an instance of the ViewModel. I added an example above.

Comment: Hi Per, I got you example to work and it will be my starting point in MVVM :) mange tak

Comment: Ok, no problem. I can recommend the silverlight 4 book by Laurent Bugnion for a decent walk through MVVM with Silverlight. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will look into that, probably good to have several resources for complicated matters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [iterate through the DataGrid's rows](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2010/05/02/accessing-of-rows-in-silverlight-datagrid.aspx), not through the items it is bound to, if you want to check a checkbox control. You would need to loop through the rows and then grab the checkbox in the proper column and set the properties on it.

But as mentioned in the comments, if the checkbox is bound to a property in the data behind the grid, then you should just be able to change that value (as long as the item exposes the INotifyPropertyChanged interface).

**Edit** Updated link

Comment: Hi Bryant I was looking for the rows property of the datagrid but it dose not exist in my datagrid: How can that be :) Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am using VS-2010 and evrything should be up to date, what could explain this lack of Rows property ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a link to a WinForms answer :) I've updated the link to a Silverlight one, however, it is probably more work than just going the MVVM route which is a better option anyways.

Comment: Thanks Bryant, I am relived. I have started reading about MVVM and I think I will be moving in that direction, but it will take awhile with my background :)